# Keynote/Powerpoint in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, powerpoint, virtual-reality, keynote

**Situation:**
I am working on a project that allow the user to practice presentations in a VR-Room. This includes the use of Powerpoint/Keynote, which is displayed on a plane. Image display is easy possible, just as video's.

**Problem:**
There's the problem. Images don't contain movement, but a powerpoint/keynote file often does. Since Unity does not support the file extension of powerpoint and keynote. Exporting to HTML and programming our own phaser for the json files and apply the animations doesnt seem worth the effort.

**Current situation:**
At this moment we converted all sheets to textures. Not using the animations.

**Request:**
In the past there used to be some plugins to display HTML on a plane (flat surface). But these seem to be outdated. Is there anyone out there who has a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "plane"?  Most English-speakers would assume you mean "airplane" or "plane ... ie flat ... surface". Neither of those meanings seems to fit your question.

Comment: He is talking about the flat surface, called plane in Unity, see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrimitiveType.Plane.html

Comment: @JeanLuc Thanks.  There's also a feature in Parallels on the Mac called Unity, which totally derailed any attempt at understanding this.  Sounds like Jonathan Nock's on the right trail.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg I dont see a relation between the things you talk about and my questions. The tags on my question contain Unity3d. I dont see the connection to Parallels or Mac.

Comment: @Aeregon Exactly.  The point of my comment to JeanLuc. I saw "Unity" and mistakenly assumed it had to do with Parallels.  It did not.  My bad.  Please ignore my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer doesn't address the specific request of displaying HTML on a quad (plane, whatever) in Unity, it is a solution that may be worth considering if it fits your scenario.

If the presentations are linear, why not record them as video?  You can easily the play the video on a quad in Unity using RenderTexture and pause it at the right moments to wait for the user to trigger the next slide/animation, whereupon the video can be played again until the next stop point.

This will require little programming on your part, but isn't the most flexible solution as it requires a linear slideshow and for you to create pause-points in the video playback at the correct timings to match the points where the slideshow naturally awaits a mouseclick from the user.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunaly we already considered this and came to the conclusion that it consumes to much time for each presentation to be manually cut.

Comment: Thought as much - well, I can't help you any further.  There seems to be a few questions on the net regarding Powerpoint and Unity, but no real solutions. :(